# Syntax for conditions(if/else) when "views" should be set as a condition in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, view, conditional-statements

My navigationbar is underneath the header... I want to change the header according to the view on which the visitor is on.

What is the syntax for a condition(if/else) when views are set as condition in Ruby on Rails?

Something like...

```
<% if index.html.erb %>
  <%= image_tag("index_background.jpg", alt: "index background") %>
<% elsif about.html.erb %>
  <%= image_tag("about_background.jpg", alt: "index background") %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag("default_background.jpg", alt: "index background") %>
<% end %>
```

If you have any question don't hesitate to ask! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those conditions are syntatically correct, you just need to get your logic straight. If those `index.html.erb` and `about.html.erb` are to check current file being rendered you should instantiate their names in you controller in some variable to compare, or use the `:controller` and `:action` params.

Maybe you need something like:

```
<% if params[:action] == 'index' %>
  <%= image_tag("index_background.jpg", alt: "index background") %>
<% elsif params[:action] == 'about' %>
  <%= image_tag("about_background.jpg", alt: "index background") %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag("default_background.jpg", alt: "index background") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use [`action_name`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/20c91119903f70eb19aed33fe78417789dbf070f/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L25):

```
# Returns the name of the action this controller is processing.
attr_internal :action_name
```

This will give you the action the user is actually in, so you could use a switch statement, eventually this would fit better than an if conditional in the case the validations you must do grow:

```
# to be added in a helper
image = case action_name
        when index then 'index'
        when about then 'about'
        else
          'default'
        end
image_tag("#{image}_background.jpg", alt: 'index background')
```

Notice `action_name` isn't documented, but it works the same way as [`ActionController::Metal#controller_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.1/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-c-controller_name).

Or I think you could create a helper method which uses asset_path to get the path of your asset using the action_name, in the case it raises an exception because it couldn't be found, then you can rescue it and show the default image:

```
# helper
module ApplicationHelper
  def action_image_background
    asset_path "#{action_name}_background"
  rescue Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound
    asset_path "default_background"
  end
end

# view
<%= image_tag action_image_background %>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for the extensive solution! There are multiple ways to accomplish this... I wish I could give both answers the green check! I will read more about action_name since I'm not that familiar with it! Thx again!

Comment: Don't worry, you're welcome. Eventually in the case your condition grows, it'd be better to think in a switch statement, although as it's now, it'd be good implementing a decorator. Last helper was just out of couriosity.

Answer (score 1):

Too much logic in the view, move this to a helper method:

```
def image_background
  img = (params[:action] || 'default') + "_background.jpg"
  image_tag img, alt: "index background"
end
```